# How to send multiple information to the next activity

Tags: android-studio

How can I send information from one activity to two activities? I would like to add another intent but I get an error about a null object... My guess is that I also would need to use another spinner for this class but just wondering if there is a short cut?

```
 add_review.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(Review.this, Add_Review.class);
            String chosenOption = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            intent.putExtra("Add a Review for", chosenOption);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            Intent send_information = new Intent(Review.this, PopularMedicalClinic.class);
            String chosenOption2 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            intent.putExtra("Name", chosenOption2);
            startActivity(send_information);
            finish();



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach in your code. You are trying to open two activity at a time. After starting first intent you call finish() method. finish() method kill current activity.

Can you explain why you want to open two activity at a time. Then I can suggest you.

Comment: I would like to just pass the same information to another activity because I need those information....

Comment: You can't send data to two different activity at the same time. If you need the value later you can store data in-memory. so you can fetch data later.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use another extra putExtra method.**
and remove finish() method. it will destroy your activity.

```
String chosenOption = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
 String chosenOption2 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(Review.this, Add_Review.class);

 intent.putExtra("Add_a_Review_for", chosenOption);
 intent.putExtra("Name", chosenOption2);
 startActivity(intent);
```